# Upgrade routine: Interaction with user confirmation

Tags: plugin-development, users, upgrade

*See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40527514/wordpress-plugin-development-upgrade-routin-interaction-with-user-confirmation) after a second think, this question is wp oriented, so I move it to here.*

I try to develop a wordpress plugin, which can be upgraded smoothly and more importantly, I want the user to choose whether to upgrade or not.

I almost got there, but I have to refresh the plugin setting page manually to see the upgrade complished.

To make my question more clear, let us see the following code:

```
<?php
class myplugin_admin_setting_class
{
    private $options;
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action('admin_menu', array(
            $this,
            'myplugin_admin_menu'
        ));
        add_action('admin_init', array(
            $this,
            'myplugin_admin_init'
        ));
    }
    public function myplugin_admin_menu()
    {
        add_options_page('My Plugin Setting Page', 'MyPlugin', 'manage_options', 'myplugin', array(
            $this,
            'myplugin_admin_page'
        ));
    }
    public function myplugin_admin_page()
    {
        $this->options = get_option('myplugin_options');
?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <form action='options.php', method='post'>
                <?php
        setting_fields('myplugin_admin_page');
        do_settings_sections('myplugin_admin_page');
        submit_button('Upgrade');
?>
        </form>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    public function myplugin_admin_init()
    {
        register_setting('myplugin_upgrade_page', 'myplugin_options');
        add_settings_section('myplugin_version', //section id
        __('Version infomation', 'myplugin') , 'myplugin_upgrade_callback', 'myplugin_upgrade_page'
        //page
        );
        add_settings_field('ver', 'Current Version:', array(
            $this,
            'myplugin_upgrade_render'
        ) , 'myplugin_upgrade_page', //page
        'myplugin_version', //section
        array(
            'field' => 'ver'
        ));
        add_settings_field('upgrade_confirm', 'Upgrade?', array(
            $this,
            'myplugin_upgrade_confirm_render'
        ) , 'myplugin_upgrade_page', //page
        'myplugin_version', //section
        array(
            'field' => 'upgrade_confirm'
        ));
    }
    public function myplugin_upgrade_render($args)
    {
        $this->options = get_option('myplugin_options');
        $field = $args['field'];
        $value = $this->options['ver'];
        //we add the hidden filed to save 'ver' option
        echo "<input type='text' size='4' disabled='disabled' value='<?php
        echo $value; ?>'>";
        echo "<input name='myplugin_options[<?php
        echo $field; ?>]' type='hidden'  value='<?php
        echo $value; ?>'>";
    }
    public function myplugin_upgrade_confirm_render($args)
    {
        $this->options = get_option('myplugin_options');
        $field = $args['field'];
        $value = $this->options['upgrade_confirm'];
?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="myplugin_options[<?php
        echo $field; ?>]" id="<?php
        echo $field; ?>" <?php
        checked($value, true); ?> value="1" />
        <?php
    }
    public function myplugin_upgrade_callback()
    {
        //check user option of upgrade true/false
        if ($this->options['upgrade_confirm']) {
            echo "Do upgrade!"; //the fake code
            $options = get_option('myplugin_options');
            $options['upgrade_confirm'] = false; // No upgrade again
            $options['ver'] = 'new version'; //update the 'ver' filed
            update_option('myplugin_options', $options);
            //I want to add a function/action/filter here to refresh the setting page but failed.

        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, I add a admin menu called MyPlugin, which has a page(called `myplugin_admin_page`) generated by the function `myplugin_admin_page()`. This page includes a section called `myplugin_version` with a filed called `ver`, the real render of this filed is done by `myplugin_upgrade_render()`. In the `add_settings_section()` we have a callback `myplugin_upgrade_callback()`, which will do the real upgrade.

The problem is that, although the database is changed after clicking on Upgrade button, but it seems that the setting page is not automatically refreshed (I also note there is a notification says that the settings saved, so maybe it reload?) since the field `ver` is not change.

Answer (score 0):

The above code has some mirror errors, and I find I can do the following to solve the problem. I have a step by step look of the submit progress, and I find that we can put the infomation in a section callback and add all the need to be updated stuffs after this section, then it will work.

The complete code like this:

```
<?php
class myplugin_admin_setting_class
{
  private $options;
  public function __construct()
  {
    add_action('admin_menu', array(
      $this,
      'myplugin_admin_menu'
    ));

    add_action('admin_init', array(
      $this,
      'myplugin_admin_init'
    ));
  }
  public function myplugin_admin_menu()
  {
    add_options_page('My Plugin Setting Page', 'MyPlugin', 'manage_options', 'myplugin', array(
      $this,
      'myplugin_admin_page'
    ));
  }
  public function myplugin_admin_page()
  {
    $this->options = get_option('myplugin_options');
?>
  <div class="wrap">
  <h2> Settings </h2>
      <form action='options.php', method='post'>
<?php
    @settings_fields('myplugin_upgrade_page');
    @do_settings_sections('myplugin_admin_page');
    submit_button('Upgrade');
?>
  </form>
  </div>
<?php
  }
  public function myplugin_admin_init()
  {
    register_setting('myplugin_upgrade_page', 'myplugin_options');
    $this->options = get_option('myplugin_options');
    $this->options['ver']='old version';
    update_option('myplugin_options', $this->options);

    add_settings_section('myplugin_version', //section id
      __('Version infomation', 'myplugin') , array( $this, 'myplugin_upgrade_callback'), 'myplugin_admin_page'
      //page
    );

    add_settings_field('ver', 'Current Version:', array(
      $this,
      'myplugin_upgrade_render'
    ) , 'myplugin_admin_page', //page
    'myplugin_version', //section
    array(
      'field' => 'ver'
    ));

    add_settings_field('upgrade_confirm', 'Upgrade?', array(
      $this,
      'myplugin_upgrade_confirm_render'
    ) , 'myplugin_admin_page', //page
    'myplugin_version', //section
    array(
      'field' => 'upgrade_confirm'
    ));
  }
  public function myplugin_upgrade_render($args)
  {
    $this->options = get_option('myplugin_options');
    $field = $args['field'];
    $value = $this->options[$field];
    //we add the hidden filed to save 'ver' option
    echo "<input type='text' size='4' disabled='disabled' value='". $value ."'>";
    echo "<input name='myplugin_options[". $field ."]' type='text'  value='".$value."'>";
  }
  public function myplugin_upgrade_confirm_render($args)
  {
    $this->options = get_option('myplugin_options');
    $field = $args['field'];
    $value = $this->options[$field];
?>
  <input type="checkbox" name="myplugin_options[<?php
    echo $field; ?>]" id="<?php
      echo $field; ?>" <?php
      checked($value, true); ?> value="1" />
<?php

  }
  public function myplugin_upgrade_callback()
  {
    //check user option of upgrade true/false

    $this->options = get_option('myplugin_options');
    if ($this->options['upgrade_confirm']) {
      echo "Do upgrade!"; //the fake code
      $options = get_option('myplugin_options');
      $options['upgrade_confirm'] = false; // No upgrade again
      $options['ver'] = 'new version'; //update the 'ver' filed
      update_option('myplugin_options', $options);
    }else{
      echo "Please check the upgrade field<br>";
      if($this->options['ver']!='new version')
      {
        echo "display upgrade details";
      }
    }
  }
}
```